# UnknownHostException When Host is Reachable

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I have some Android code that I'm hoping to pull data off of a webpage and display it as text. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error, even though it has proper permissions and everything:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "ephemeraltech.com": No address associated with hostname

Here is my manifest file permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

And here is the code itself:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.round_activity_my);

        TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        myAsyncTask mTask = new myAsyncTask();
        mTask.execute("http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php");

        /* final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        }); */
    }

    private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
        public String resultText;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... str) {
            try {
                System.out.println("testing");
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    resultText = reader.readLine();
                    webs.close();
                    System.out.println("testing II");
                } catch(Exception e){
                    resultText = "hi";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String resultText) {
        TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        mTextView.setText("sdfdfdfdf");
        System.out.println("Testing III");
    }
}
```

I have no clue why am getting it. Anyone have any idea?

EDIT: It's an Android Wear emulator, and it is paired to a phone that has Wifi, so I don't know why it can't reach the internet.

Comment: Try this url `http://www.ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php`

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: you hv deviece or emulator?

Comment: It's running on an emulator

Comment: go to browser of your emulator and check if internet is working ?

Comment: It is. It's a Android Wear emulator, but it is connecting to the internet properly

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Hurl.it](http://hurl.it) if its throws correct response, your device internet problem